# Shadow copy in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, volume-shadow-copy

Can the `volume shadow copy` system being installed on XP Pro standalone?

If not, what are some suitable free alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it is part of XP Professional anyway (it comes with the ntbackup.exe).

I found an overview of its as [part of the Microsoft Windows XP Professional overview](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntbackup_backup_snapshot.mspx?mfr=true) on MSDN, which I would also take as indication that it is built into XP Pro.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814583 and http://www.ntbackup.us/Articles/install-ntbackup-xp-home.htm

Comment: @akira: will that give the 'previous versions` of files on the local XP machine?

Comment: @CJ7: did i miss that part of your question in your question?

Comment: It *is* part of XP, but is of very little use, since it doesn't allow permanent snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article about Shadow Cop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy)y says "The Volume Snapshot Service was first added to Microsoft Windows in Windows XP"